# Replace Components.classesByID with document.implementation.createDocument

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am not the author of this code, but it is no longer maintained. So I am trying to fix it, but I have very little experience in javascript.
Since Firefox 9, Components.classesByID["{3a9cd622-264d-11d4-ba06-0060b0fc76dd}"]. has been obsolete. Instead, it is suggested that 
document.implementation.createDocument be used. Can someone here show me how to implement these changes? I seem to be, just banging my head with everything I have tried.

The example given at Mozilla developer network is:

```
    var doc = document.implementation.createDocument ("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", null);
var body = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "body");
body.setAttribute("id", "abc");
doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);
alert(doc.getElementById("abc")); // [object HTMLBodyElement]
```

and the code in the .jsm I am trying to fix is:

```
createFgImageData: function helpers_createFgImageData() {

    // I don't know how to load images synchronously *FIX*
    // Until then, this awesome bitmap format below will do. 

    this.fgImageData = {};
    this.fgImageData["check"] = [
        "      *",
        "     **",
        "*   ***",
        "** *** ",
        "*****  ",
        " ***   ",
        "  *    "];
    this.fgImageData["radio"] = [
        " **** ",
        "******",
        "******",
        "******",
        "******",
        " **** "];
    this.fgImageData["menu-ltr"] = [
        "*   ",
        "**  ",
        "*** ",
        "****",
        "*** ",
        "**  ",
        "*   "];
    this.fgImageData["menu-rtl"] = [
        "   *",
        "  **",
        " ***",
        "****",
        " ***",
        "  **",
        "   *"];            

    // I think I'm doing something slightly wrong when creating the document
    // but I'm not sure. It works though. *FIX*

    var domi = Components.classesByID["{3a9cd622-264d-11d4-ba06-0060b0fc76dd}"].
                    createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMDOMImplementation);
    this.document = domi.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", null);
    this.canvas = this.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html:canvas");

    for(var name in this.fgImageData) {
        if (this.fgImageData.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            var data = this.fgImageData[name];
            var width = data[0].length;
            var height = data.length;

            this.canvas.width = width;
            this.canvas.height = height;
            var g = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            var idata = g.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            for(var y=0, oy=0; y<height; y++, oy+=idata.width*4)
                for(var x=0, ox=oy; x<width; x++, ox+=4)
                    idata.data[ox+3] = data[y][x] == " " ? 0 : 255;

            this.fgImageData[name] = idata;
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to an actual window (like in a JavaScript module) it's probably best to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) to create an HTML document (thanks to Boris for this hint). It [can be instantiated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsIDOMParser) in any context:

```js
var parser = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"]
                       .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMParser);
var dummyDocument = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'/>";
this.document = parser.parseFromString(dummyDocument, "text/xml");
this.canvas = this.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
```

Note that the second parameter to `createElementNS()` should be `"canvas"`, not `"html:canvas"` - the namespace is specified in the first parameter. Also note that as of Firefox 12 DOMParser can also parse HTML code (MIME type `"text/html"`) so alternatively you could write:

```js
this.document = parser.parseFromString("", "text/html");
```

A minimal HTML document is indeed the empty string.

Comment: And thank you Mr. Adblock for your answer, I have tried the code and it works exactly as expected!

Answer (score 1):

There is not preexisting document to work with in a JSM.  You have several options:

1. Pass in a relevant parent document from the caller.
2. Create a blank document using DOMParser on an empty string or XHR to an empty data: URI.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your reply and getting us going in the right direction!